# select from database where date < today mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql database which contain date like this value

```
22 Jan 2019 11:03
```

I want to select all records that have values less than today , so I wrote this query

```
select username from radcheck
where DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(value,'%d %M %Y') ,'%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

but this query return all records even those not expired .
where is my problem

Comment: `%d %M %Y` is not a good format for sorting dates as you are effecctively sorting on the day of the month. Try `%Y %M %d` instead

Comment: *which contain date like this value* Does this value is stored in string datatype field really?

Comment: I tried your way @paul but still return all records

Comment: yes it is varchar(225) @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT username 
FROM radcheck
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`value`,'%d %b %Y %H:%i') < CURRENT_DATE
```